# git ignore all files of a certain type, except those in a specific subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure like this:

- root

  - folder1

    - abc.json
    - def.json
    - somedir

      - more.json
  - folder2

    - qwe.json
    - rty.json
  - spec

    - mock1.json
    - mock2.json
    - somedir

      - more_mocks.json

Now using a `.gitignore` I want to ignore all `*.json` files except for the ones in the `spec`.  I don't want to use a `.gitignore` in `folder1` and `folder2` because there are a ton of these and they will get added to a lot, and I'm sure I will forget to move the right `.gitignore` file in place.

In addition, there may be more nested directories with JSON files, and this rule needs to apply to all subdirectories as well.

So how do I ignore all files of a type, except for a certain subdirectory?

Answer (score 461, accepted):

> An optional prefix `!` which negates the
> pattern; any matching file excluded by
> a previous pattern will become
> included again. If a negated pattern
> matches, this will override lower
> precedence patterns sources.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

```
*.json
!spec/*.json
```

Comment: You could also add a .gitignore to spec that contains !/*.json, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks!  Although in my case, I realized that I want to ignore nothing in my spec directory at all.  So I am able to get away with a very simple `!spec`.  Works like a charm.

Comment: While Amber's answer works when spec is a directory under the top level (i.e. /spec), it doesn't work for me when spec is a subdirectory, e.g. /a/spec or a/b/spec. Using git 1.7.5.4

Comment: The linked doc no longer appears to be valid. Maybe this is comparable? http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html

Comment: @PeterLewis (for future visitors): such a case can be handled by creating a .gitignore file in the relevant subdirectory.

Comment: While I'm not sure what the exact semantics are, for a second-level directory `/assets/components` (from MODx, if anybody cares), this worked for me: `*`, `!/.gitignore`, `!/assets`, `/assets/*`, `!/assets/components`, finally `.DS_Store` etc for good measure. Note the heavy use of absolute paths; the semantics are hugely different with relative paths, although I don't fully understand why...

Comment: on further examination, `!/assets/components/**` works better ;)

Comment: What about if there needs to be an exception for more than 1 directory ? Wouldn't the second rule cancel the first one ?

Comment: This solution for me only ignored the `json` files in `spec` directly, not the one in the `somedir` subdirectory from the question. I needed to use `!spec/**/*.json` in order to make sure the `more_mocks.json` was committed as well.