# Ignore file types except within a specific folder (and all sub folders)?

Tags: git

I'm trying to configure a `.gitignore` file such that all files with a certain extension are ignored, *except* where they appear within a specific folder, or any sub folder of that folder. I've tried the following which does not work:

```
*.lib
!Libraries/
```

A second question I have is, do negated exclusions only apply to the immediately preceding rule, or do every rule you've defined up to that point?-

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621072/git-ignore-all-files-of-a-certain-type-except-those-in-a-specific-subfolder?rq=1) almost answers my question, but doesn't help for sub folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you meant is ignore all `*.lib` except when they're inside `/Libraries`, try this out:

```
# The root directory's .gitignore
*.lib
!/Libraries/*.lib

# The .gitignore under /Libraries directory
!*.lib
```

The `.gitignore` is parsed from top to bottom. Any rule can override prior rules.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a double asterisk, `**`. Something like this in your `.gitignore` might work:

```
*.lib
!/Libraries/**/*.lib
```

The double asterisk matches any combination of subdirectories. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681294/1095946) explains how it works fairly well.

As for your second question, @Tuxdude is correct: rules will override other rules up to that point due to the way the `.gitignore` is parsed.

Comment: I tried this one, but it only seems to track the .lib files directly under `/Libraries` but not if they're under any of the sub-directories of `/Libraries`

Comment: A couple of notes: `**` matches *literally* any number of directories, including none, so the second line is redundant, and `**` parsing was added in git 1.8.2, which was early 2013. Testing shows this working for me?