# .gitgnore file but not when under a specific directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a Java project in which I am ignoring all jar files with the pattern in *.gitignore*:

```
*.jar
```

However, there are dependency files in the folder *dependencies* which are jar files but I don't want to exclude them.
How do I setup the *.gitignore* for this?

Comment: I read that answer. But I was still not sure that will it work for a variant of that issue. And for future reference of other people having this same issue.

Comment: I don't agree, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621090/989920) is almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated pattern to include files that were ignored by a previous pattern:

```
*.jar
!dependencies/*.jar
```