# How to automatically exclude some file types in git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I usually add the files and extensions that I want to ignore to .git/info/exclude to have a rather neat repository. I'm on a mac and for example I always need to exclude the .DS_Store file that is created. I was wondering if there is a way to change the default *exclude* file.

Comment: Check .gitignore : https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621072/git-ignore-all-files-of-a-certain-type-except-those-in-a-specific-subfolder

Comment: If you mean ignoring the folder for all repositories, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore

Comment: @KevinHoerr Thanks. That is exactly what I meant. So that any new repository made will automatically ignore certain files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Git ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)

Answer (score 2):

Create `.gitignore_global` file somewhere, for example user directory is a good place.
Add all files and directories you want to ignore locally.
Then you need to tell git where is this file by using this command:

```bash
$ git config --global core.excludesfile <your-git-ignore-file>
```

if you are put the file in user directory, then command could be this in windows:

```bash
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to make your global default ignore file, simply run:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.config/git/
echo "**/.DS_Store" >> ~/.config/git/ignore
```

This will work for you locally for all your repos, but won't be part of the repos or seen by other developers. For that, you could just append the contents of this personal static file to the exclude files of specific repos though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*`  and other operators for pattern matching. See [this link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more info. For .DS_Store you can add the following to .gitignore .

```
**/.DS_Store
```

For Ignoring all pdf files you can add:

```
**/*.pdf
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks but I was after an automatic way for any new repo to include this pattern in the exclude file.