# How to ignore .DS_Store files in macOS in git without adding it in .gitignore file?

Tags: git, macos, gitignore

I switched from Ubuntu to macOS, and now I frequently use Git. However, there's a file in macOS called **.DS_Store** that is automatically generated by macOS Finder. Is there any way to ignore the **.DS_Store** file in the Git working directory without adding it to the .gitignore file?

Comment: See [How to automatically exclude some file types in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854568/how-to-automatically-exclude-some-file-types-in-git). While it doesn't specifically and explicitly mention .DS_Store, the solution applies for any kind of file type, _including_ .DS_Store.

Comment: See also [.gitignore all the .DS_Store files in every folder and subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18393498/2745495), where some of the answers explain how to remove it from your repo (in case they were accidentally committed) _and_ how to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score -1):

There's no magic, of course, but you can set up a global .gitignore, as described here:

https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/db7f57fff2fb6998a16c