# path to .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a repo structure like this.

`Courses/course name/week/question/code scripts`

Courses is the folder where I initialized the git repo in the beginning.
What I need to know is what path should I give to the `.gitignore` file to make sure that the `.exe` files at the following locations are ignored.

`Courses/DSA Specialization/Course1/Week1/Problem1/abc.exe`

`Courses/DSA Specialization/Course1/Week1/Problem2/abcd.exe`

`Courses/DSA Specialization/Course1/Week2/Problem1/abce.exe`

and so on.....

I tried adding

`*.exe`

`**/**/**/**/*.exe`

`Courses/DSA Specialization/Course1/**/**/*.exe`

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`**` can match any number of (sub)directories. You don't need `**/**/**`.

- If you want to **match any `.exe`** file **inside any level of subdirectories** of `Course1`, use:

  ```
  Courses/DSA Specialization/Course1/**/*.exe
  ```
- If you want to **match `.exe`** files **inside exactly 2-levels of subdirectories** of `Course1`, use

  ```
  Courses/DSA Specialization/Course1/*/*/*.exe
  ```

Comment: I added this, but it didn't work. Is there any restriction regarding the location of the .gitignore file because I have placed it in Courses folder ?

Comment: @RahulDhankhar: Yes, the location of `.gitignore` is important. All paths inside the file are relative to where the file is. So, if you place it inside the Courses folder, your paths should start with `DSA Specialization/ ....`

Answer (score 2):

How about using `**.exe` in the `.gitignore` at the root of your repository?
This will ignore any `.exe` anywhere in your repository.

If for some reason you need exceptions to this rule, I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621072/git-ignore-all-files-of-a-certain-type-except-those-in-a-specific-subfolder) might help.

Comment: Seems like the best way to do it. There may be exceptions but generally speaking it's good advise to not checking in binary files like `*.exe`. (Unless you use something like [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/))